# Flutter Web App Blank after Firebase Deploy

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

My Web app works fine when I run it in debug mode using vs-code and chrome, but when I use `flutter build web` followed by `Firebase deploy` and open the app using the hosting link, my app is blank.
When I inspect it

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at Object.a0s (animation_controller.dart:248)
    at Object.a56 (cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart:47)
    at cloud_firestore_web.dart:26
    at a0o.a (async_patch.dart:308)
    at a0o.$2 (main.dart.js:22669)
    at Object.a4 (async_patch.dart:238)
    at Object.IT (main.dart.js:7072)
    at js_helper.dart:3221
    at js_helper.dart:3221
    at dartProgram (js_helper.dart:3221)
```

This is the error I see in the console.
I have tried most of the solutions on the web, any and all help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Trying to deploy to *surge.sh* same blank behavior.